# smooth shading error on a low poy model creating sharp edges

Tags: shaders, shadows

I have a low poly model with smooth shading enabled on all faces. unfortunately, when I go into rendered view, I see odd sharp lines on the edges and tris not previously seen in lookdev view:[image: Look dev]
Rendered view:[image: Rendered]
Edit mode:[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try recalculating normals ctrl+N in edit mode or merge vertices by distance also in edit mode I think alt+M for the merge

Comment: no, I tried that and it doesn't seem to work, so I'm not sure what's up. If it helps it was imported from instant meshes as an obj

Answer (score 0):

Its probably due to lighting does it still persist when you move your light source around, and from the image of your node editor your normal map isn't applied yet.

Comment: Yes, the problem continues when the light source is moved and also when all the textures are applied, but the problem does seem to be reduced when I use a larger light source, though that is to be expected. I wonder if this might be a bug?

Comment: so it might be the "Terminator effect" (pixellisation effect on the border of the shadow)... to fix this you need to increase the size of your light (called angle in 2.8). I've heard it's a problem that should be fixed in some next versions of Blender.

Answer (score 0):

Your low poly and high poly maybe rendering on top of each other. Check your render and view toggles in the Outliner.